# Merge multiple jq invocations to sort and limit the content of a stream of objects

Tags: sorting, jq

I have a json stream of updates for products, and I'm trying to get the last X versions sorted by version (they are sorted by release date currently).

It looks like jq can't sort a stream of objects directly, `sort_by` only works on arrays, and I couldn't find a way to collect a stream into an array that doesn't involve piping the output of `jq -c` to `jq -s`.

My current solution:

```sh
< xx \
    jq -c '.[] | select(.platform | contains("Unix"))' \
    | jq -cs 'sort_by(.version) | reverse | .[]' \
    | head -5 \
    | jq -C . \
    | less
```

I expected to be able to use

```sh
jq '.[] | select(...) | sort_by(.version) | limit(5) | reverse'
```

but I couldn't find a thing that `limit`s and `sort_by` doesn't work on non arrays.

I am testing this on atlassian's json for releases: https://my.atlassian.com/download/feeds/archived/bamboo.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `jq` you can always contain the results to an array using the `[..]` that put the results to an array for the subsequent functions to operate on. Your given requirement could be simply done as

```
jq '[.[] | select(.platform | contains("Unix"))] | sort_by(.version) | limit(5;.[])'
```

See it working on [jq playground](https://jqplay.org/s/APxS1JnCmI) tested on v1.6

and with added `reverse()` function, introduce an another level of array nesting. Use `reverse[]` to dump the objects alone

```
jq '[[.[] | select(.platform | contains("Unix"))] | sort_by(.version) | limit(5;.[]) ] | reverse'
```

Comment: Perfect, I didn't know you could wrap a block in square brackets to use it as an array. Also, thanks for the limit example, I didn't realise it needed a selector.
I went with `[.[] | select(.platform | contains("Unix"))] | sort_by(.version) | reverse | limit(5; .[])`

Comment: `limit/2` is most useful when the input is already a stream. But since it's an array, it would be easier to just slice it. `... | sort_by(.version)[:5]`